# Youtube Music API documentation

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, youtube, youtube-api

I want to implement [YouTube music](https://music.youtube.com/) in my app, I did some searches and I found out that there is a YouTube music api but I couldn't find any documentation about it.

**My questions:**

1. Does Youtube Music have an API or an SDK for android?
2. Does anyone have some ideas about it?

Comment: What features are you looking for for such an API?

Answer (score 3):

At this time there is no YouTube Music api.  Anything you may have seen on the internet is probably third party hacked, and would most likely be against googles TOS.

If google ever does release one it will probably be listed here.

[All Develop products](https://developers.google.com/products/develop/#y)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you see any other alternatives?

Comment: As Google and YouTube own YouTube Music the only thing to do would be to wait for them to release one.  There can be no alternative.